# Is QCD parity conserving also non-perturbatively?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, parity, non-perturbative

Since QCD is fundamentally non-perturbative at low energies one may ask if QCD is still Parity conserving. In the path-integral formalism using the Faddeev–Popov ghosts as gauge fixing terms the measure is given by $\mathcal{D}G_\mu\mathcal{D}\bar{c}\mathcal{D}c\mathcal{D}\bar{q}\mathcal{D}q$, where $c$ and $\bar{c}$ are the ghosts, $q$ and $\bar{q}$ are the quarks and $G_\mu$ are the gluons. The parity transformation should map $q\rightarrow \gamma^0 q$, $\bar{q}\rightarrow \bar{q}\gamma^0 $, $c/\bar{c}\rightarrow c/\bar{c}$(since they are scalars) and $G_i\rightarrow -G_i$; $G_0\rightarrow G_0$.

Therefore the whole measure should transform $\mathcal{D}G_\mu\mathcal{D}\bar{c}\mathcal{D}c\mathcal{D}\bar{q}\mathcal{D}q\rightarrow -\mathcal{D}G_\mu\mathcal{D}\bar{c}\mathcal{D}c\mathcal{D}\bar{q}\mathcal{D}q$ in $(3+1)$ dimensions. This would violate Parity non-perturbatively even if the Lagrangian is Parity conserving. Am I missing something or is this really true for non-perturbative QCD?

Comment: What you describe does not discriminate between energies, the transformation you are performing must have a problem since you could say it also applies for the high energy regime where no such a problem is present given that QCD is not a chirality violating theory a priori (no theta-term)

Comment: Yes but I do not see anything wrong except if the ghosts transform somehow non-trivially. But it may come from the fact that for the high energy behaviour we only consider n-point functions i.e. ratios of the path integral which cancel the minus sign. Therefore this sign could only affect the vacuum structure of QCD imho similarly to the theta vacua for the axial anomaly.

Comment: There is probably a better answer to this but $SU(3)$ leads to 8 types of gluons so that negative sign would appear an even number of times.

Comment: @krabbypatty but then again also in the low energy, what is there besides $n$-point functions. I suspect there might be an absolute value involved in the Jacobian, and as long as this Jacobian is not field dependant it will always cancel in ratios as you say. Concerning the argument on gluon number, I think is not really that, it should be an SU(N) argument. This is not something special from SU(3) I believe, but ...

Comment: @ohneVal But if the jacobian has the absolute value included then also the chiral anomaly should not be an issue. I think the Absolute value of the determinant is only needed if you have off-diagonal entries otherwise you just exchange the integration boundaries.

Comment: Now that I think about it in the classical definition of the path integral discretised in time and space such a parity transformation should be very ill-defined since we would get an  infinite number of minus signs due to $dG_i(x_n^j)dG_i(x_n^{j+1})...dG_i(x_{n+1}^j)$